# $a d(x,y)=d(a x, a y)$?

Tags: metric-spaces

I know that $a|x-y|=|ax-ay|$

Question: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space (arbitrary) :  $a d(x,y)=d(a x, a y)$?

Comment: In an abitrary metric space $ax$ is not even a well-defined object. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space

Comment: Yes, but, if $ax\ in X$ (for all $x$), is it valid?

Comment: If it is valid then who knows what it even means. And what if $a<0$. As I mentioned in the previous comment the notion of normed vector space probably answers your doubts. Have a look at it.

Comment: thanks. (I forgot to mention that $a>0$). The context of my question is showing or refuting that $rB(0,1)=B(0,r)$ (with $B(0,1)$ unit ball), i.e, 
$\left\{rx\in X: d(x,0)<1\right\}=\left\{x\in X: d(x,0)<r\right\}$

Comment: See, here you are using not only the metric space properties of Euclidean space, but also its vector space properties, and also the fact that these two play along nicely. Which is why we are telling you to say "normed vector space" rather than "metric space".

Comment: The question makes no sense because in $X$,  the expression $ax$ has no meaning. For example, what does $ax$ mean if $a$ is a real number and $x$ a graph? If $x$ is a topological space? If $x$ is an equivalence relation? An arbitrary metric space can have ANY set as base set $X$. So the elements of $X$ can be anything and multiplication by real numbers is not defined for a lot of things.

Comment: oh I see. My question originates from trying to prove that the open ball $B(x,r)$ is an open set since $B(0,1)$ is an open set, then, by a translation of the origin $0\to x$ and another dilation of the radius $1\to r$, verify that $B(x,r)=x+rB(0,1)$ (this is notational but must be interpreted as a set), but, from the comments, I see that it is not true that $B(0 ,r)=rB(0,1)$ :(

Comment: It may be that $0$ is not even an element of $X$, so $B(0,r)$ and $B(0,1)$ make no sense in a general metric space.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can consider the discrete metric on any vector space given by $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ and $d(x,y)=0$ else.

A probably more interesting question is which 'non-norm' metrics satisfy this property on a vector space. Or perhaps you should wonder what this property imply on the metric space.